# Creating a dictionary with automated population in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to find a more effective approach to populate dictionaries for a 100,000+ row dataset imported from csv in python. I am trying to fill the Manager IDs and Names without having to write all the names and numbers out.

This is what it looks like:

```
    Manager 1 ID   Manager 1 Name     Manager 2 ID   Manager 2 Name     
1      123         Michael Scott        124          Snow White 
2      123                              124             
3      123         Michael Scott        124
4      321         John Doe             234          Bugs Bunny
5      321                              234
6      442                              345          Porky Pig
7      442         Daffy Duck           345                   
.
.
.
14732  734         George Lopez         763        
14733  734                              763          Steve Austin
```

I have created a dictionary like this:

```
 dict1 = {123:'Michael Scott', 321: 'John Doe', 442:'Daffy Duck'}
 dict2 = {124:'Snow White', 234:'Bugs Bunny', 345:'Porky Pig'}
```

Is there a way to iterate through the columns and rows to make it run through the numbers to get the names without having to input them all myself.
To have it look like this:

```
   Manager 1 ID     Manager 1 Name     Manager 2 ID     Manager 2 Name 
1      123           Michael Scott          124           Snow White
2      123           Michael Scott          124           Snow White
3      123           Michael Scott          124           Snow White
4      321           John Doe               234           Bugs Bunny
5      321           John Doe               234           Bugs Bunny 
6      442           Daffy Duck             345           Porky Pig
7      442           Daffy Duck             345           Porky Pig
.
.
.
14732  734           George Lopez           763           Steve Austin
14733  734           George Lopez           763           Steve Austin
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do it following way, consider following simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Man1ID":[123,123,123,321,321,442,442]})
dict1 = {123:'Michael Scott', 321: 'John Doe', 442:'Daffy Duck'}
df["Man1Name"] = df["Man1ID"].replace(dict1)
print(df)
```

gives output

```
   Man1ID       Man1Name
0     123  Michael Scott
1     123  Michael Scott
2     123  Michael Scott
3     321       John Doe
4     321       John Doe
5     442     Daffy Duck
6     442     Daffy Duck
```

*(tested in pandas 1.5.2)*